# I need to fetch older tweets, i.e. from 01-01-2019 to 01-12-2019, by using the standard API (not premium or enterprise) using Tweepy

Tags: python, tweepy, sentiment-analysis, twitterapi-python

```
import tweepy
import re
import csv
import json
import got
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler("APIKEY","APISCRETKEY")
auth.set_access_token("ACCESS-TOKEN","ACESS-TOKEN-SCRETKEY")
api = tweepy.API(auth,wait_on_rate_limit=True)
```

I am getting the data of the past 7 days only after passing the API credentials.

```
follow = api.followers()
#print(follow)
tag = '#lecoqsportif OR #parfum'
fileName = '_'.join(re.findall("#(\w+)",tag))
print(fileName)
with open('%s.csv' % (fileName),'w',encoding='utf-8') as file:
    w = csv.writer(file)
    w.writerow(['timestamp', 'tweet_text', 'username', 'all_hashtags', 'followers_count'])
    for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search,q = tag+'-filter:retweets',lang="en").items(10000):
        w.writerow([tweet.created_at,tweet.text.replace('\n',''),tweet.user.screen_name,[e['text'] for e in tweet._json['entities']['hashtags']],tweet.user.followers_count])
```

Even if I request for 10000 records, I am getting only less than 1000 records that correspond to only 1 week of data. I want to get the data from the past 12 months using the standard API (which is not a paid version). Is this possible? If so, please provide me the solution.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you're going to want to regenerate your credentials now.

This is not possible with the standard search API:

> Keep in mind that the search index has a 7-day limit. In other words, no tweets will be found for a date older than one week.

https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/search/api-reference/get-search-tweets

For help with markdown, see https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help.

Comment: So, you are telling that it is not possible to get the data of beyond 1 week with standard api.

Comment: Yes, you'd have to use the premium or enterprise search APIs to do so.